# Real analysis question - find the supremum?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $S = \{\frac{2}{n^2} − \frac{3}{m} : m, n \in\mathbb N\}$.

Then $\sup S = ?$

(a) $1$, (b) $2$, (c) $−3$, (d) $0$, (e) $3$.

How would you solve this kind of problem?  This was on my midterm and I got it wrong.  I think a similar one could be on the final but I can't figure out how to do it.  The correct answer is (b) $2$, so could someone please explain how to get to that answer?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{2}{n^2 }- \frac{3}{m}$ increases as $n$ decreases and $m$ increases. so set $n = 1$ and let $m$ tend toward infinity.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  So basically you're saying that to find the supremum of a question similar to this one, I need to figure out how the term INCREASES in general, and then set n and m accordingly?  You chose n=1 because that's the natural number that leads to the smallest denominator (and thus the largest number), right?

Comment: Also - just to make sure I know how to find the infimum as well.  Is inf(S) = -3 here, by letting m=1 and n tend towards infinity?

Comment: yes I agree with everything you just said. the supremum is the smallest number which is greater than or eqaul to every element of your set. likewise the infimum is the greatest lower bound.